# CharInSet function is not working in Delphi using TMS WEB Core

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, tms-web-core

I've written the following code on a button click event:

```
procedure TForm1.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  c: Char;
begin
  c := 'A';
  if CharInSet(c, ['0'..'9']) then
    ShowMessage('The character is a digit')
  else
    ShowMessage('The character is not a digit');
end;
```

But this gives a weird error:

> [Error] Unit1.pas(31): not yet implemented: :TBinaryExpr [20170714171218]

I'm not sure if the error is on the `CharInSet` function or on the `['0'..'9']`, but the error is definitely happening on that line with the `CharInSet`.

It seems like `CharInSet` either isn't supported in TMS WEB Core, or the way I'm using it isn't supported in TMS WEB Core.

How can I use `CharInSet` in TMS WEB Core?

Comment: It is possible that TMS WEB Core is not able of working with sets. Perhaps TMS WEB Core miggt support usage of [System.Character.TCharacter.IsNumber](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Character.TCharacter.IsNumber) function or some equivalent instead.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have the concept of sets, AFAIK. If TMS Web Core outputs JavaScript code, and that language doesn't support a language construct, and they haven't implemented a way to work around that missing construct, it would explain the issue. Have you contacted TMS support directly to ask about whether Delphi sets are supported, and if not whether they are on the roadmap for their product?